# silent way to import registry file via puppet module

Tags: windows, powershell, puppet

I've got a group of `.reg` files that I need to import via puppet. I saw the puppetlabs registry module, but in that there is no way to import `.reg` files. Is there any way to silently import `.reg` files via puppet?

Answer (score 2):

`regedit.exe` has a [switch](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/82821) `/s` for silently importing registry files. Import the file via an [`exec` resource](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/types/exec.html).

```puppet
$file = 'C:\path\to\your.reg'
exec { "import $file":
    command => "regedit.exe /s $file",
    require => File[$file],
}
```

Alternatively you could use the [`reg.exe`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/82821) commandline utility, as @AlexK suggested in the comments:

```
$file = 'C:\path\to\your.reg'
exec { "import $file":
    command => "reg.exe import $file",
    require => File[$file],
}
```